# how to combine all functions of multi subclasses inherited from one class

Tags: c#, subclass

I need to use several functions embeded in different subclasses inherited from one class. For example, `ListViewA` and `ListViewB` from `ListView`. The subclasses are from third-part software and opensource. Is there a simple way to combine all the functions?

Comment: Make an extension method and in that combine all the functions you need.

Comment: What you mean by combine all the functions? Is it possible to reword your question, then we grab your intention clearly

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
foreach(ListView unknownListView in unknownObjectList)
{
    if (unknownListView is ListViewA )
    {
       var LWA = unknownListView as ListViewA;
       // ... do something with ListViewA 
    }
    if (unknownListView is ListViewB )
    {
       var LWB = unknownListView as ListViewB ;
       // ... do something with ListViewB 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Spetially speaking, ListViewA can save and restore the columns info, and ListViewB can sort multi columns. Is there a simple way to generate a subclass or something that can both save and restore the configuration and sorting, without too much re-coding work?

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide some more code so you can get specific answers, its too general at the moment. im not sure i understood the problem ut you can crearte a new class which contains objects of both clases inside, but you will still have to implement the methods inside which will access the matching object accorsing tot he desired functionality

Comment: To be specific, is there a method to rewrite or overload a internal method of a class without inheriting?

Comment: something like this. I do not how to enter return.

Comment: something like this. I do not know how to enter return.

Comment: I wonder if there exists a method that can change or rewrite the protected function of a class by classname and function Name, for example the constructor function, without inheriting.

Comment: maybe reflection is needed.